# JBoss 7 remount connect

Tags: jboss, centos, jboss7.x, centos7

I performed a fresh install of JBoss 7 on Centos 7.

JBoss server is started in standalone mode:

```
● jboss.service - SYSV: JBoss AS Standalone

   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/jboss)

   Active: active (running) since Tue 2016-01-19 16:07:21 EET; 17min ago
```

But I can't access `http://localhost:8080` and the JBoss server is not listening for any connections.

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       
PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
18268/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
1620/master
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      
18268/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      
1620/master
```

My standalone.xml

```
 <interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:10.10.8.32}"/>
    </interface>
```

Can anyone help me find the way to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

So, I can't resolve this problem. JBoss 7 , maybe , have some  incompatibility with Centos 7. I simply install WildFly 9 and it's works fine.